# Including PDF pages from URL

Tags: external-files, pdfpages

Does anyone know a way of including an external PDF document from a URL? When using pdfpages the following will not work:

```
\includepdf[pages=-]{http://www.mydomain.com/myfile.pdf}
```

My reason for asking is that I would like to avoid putting PDF files in my git repository.

Comment: You can have the pdf in the folder, where you work on the .tex files without adding them to the git version control. But as soon as you work with multiple people on the .tex on multiple machines this do not fix your problem. Interesting question!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 7):

The package `pdfpages` isn't capable of downloading pdf files. But you may write a command yourself that first downloads the requested files (e.g. using wget) and imports them afterwards in the known manner.

EDIT: See also the package `download`:
http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/download/download.pdf

Using this it seems to be rather easy to create the necessary command as the command `\download[filename]{url}` does anything for you.

Answer (score 4):

you can use ConTeXt, then it is possible:

```
\starttext
\insertpages[http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/download/download.pdf][n=2][width=18cm]
\stoptext
```

for the first two pages.